# Make a Flutter alertdialog when the app open

Tags: flutter, shake, flutter-alertdialog

So I want my Flutter app to make an alertdialog as soon as the app opens and make it collapse when I shake the mobile how can I make it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't give you the exact solution, but I'll try to guide you.

[showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) function lets you open a modal dialog.

You can use [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method inside [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) of [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) to call showDialog on start (when your page is being build for the first time).

There's a [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/shake) for detecting phone shake.

When you detect a shake, you should check whether dialog is opened or not (probably store some flag) and if it is opened, call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` to close it.

UPD: ok here comes the solution:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ShakeDetector detector;
  bool dialogOpened = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (cxt) => AlertDialog(content: Text('shake to close')),
      ).then((_) => dialogOpened = false);
    });

    detector = ShakeDetector.autoStart(
      onPhoneShake: () {
        if (dialogOpened) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }

        detector?.stopListening();
        detector = null;
      }
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    detector?.stopListening();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

Also add `shake_event: ^0.0.4` to dependecies in *pubspec.yaml*.

Comment: I can't figure out why u won't give me the exact solution for my problem i know most of the components that u mentioned and tried so much before i ask here but nothing themed right so i came here to ask for a solution

Comment: @MohamedEldereny Because your question looks like you haven't tried anything at all, that's why it's getting downvoted. Though what you want to implement isn't so hard to do.

Comment: @MohamedEldereny Ok, here comes the solution. Please, upvote/accept the answer, if it helped you.